# High number of connections to Airflow Metadata DB

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I tried to find information about the number of connections that Airflow establishes with the metadata database instance (Postgres in my case).

By running `select * from pg_stat_activity` I realized it creates at least 7 connections whose states change between `idle` and `idle in transaction`. The queries are registered as `COMMIT` or `SELECT 1` (mostly). This was using the LocalExecutor on Airflow 2.1, but I tested with an installation of Airflow 1.10 having the same results.

Is anyone aware of where these connections come from? And, is there a way (and a reason) to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Airflow will Open big number of connections - basically every process it creates will almost for sure open at least one connection. This is "known" characteristics of Apache Airflow.

If you are using MySQL - this is not a big issue as MySQL is good in handling multiple connections (it multiplexes incoming connnections via threads). Postgres uses process-per-connection approach which is much more resource-hungry.

The recommended way to handle that (Postgres is the most stable backend for Airflow) is to use PGBouncer to proxy such connections to Postgres.

In our Official Helm Chart, PGBouncer is used by default, when Postgres is used. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html

I Highly recommend this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I don't want to go with the Helm Chart, is it fair to say that I can simply create a PGBouncer instance in-between my Airflow server and Postgres DB to deal with this? Also, I'd be interesting to have detailed documentation about how Airflow interacts with the Metadata database instead of just having to solve the limitation with PGBouncer. Please let me know if you can point to any resource.

Comment: Yes. That should be it. Actually here is the documentation about the architecture https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/overview.html  - I think this information is not there, but if you think it's good idea, I would love if you could contribute a chapter about it. I think users like you who stumble upon it and get help from the community who explained them that, are best to explain this for others who will stumble upon this (committers have often too many assumptions). 

Airflow is community-developed so any help with that is more than welcome.

Comment: Would you like to contribute such description back? It's super easy - when you open the page there is a "suggest a change on this page" button and you you can add a paragraph about it without actually even having a development environment,

Comment: Is there a way we can control without using pgbouncer?